# Is a fixed point possible at a discontinuity in the vector field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, fixed-points

Consider a dynamical system of the following form:

$$
\dot{x} = x(1-x)-xy
$$
$$
\dot{y} = y\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)
$$

Would the point $(0,0)$ be a fixed point of the system? Clearly, the vector field is discontinuous at this point, which leads me to believe that the point is not a fixed point. However, using PPlane to display the phase portrait of the system, I noted that some trajectories asymptotically converge to $(0,0)$:
[Phase portrait of the above system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOpNN.png)

More generally, what should one do when faced with a problem where the vector field is discontinuous?

Comment: The field isn't even defined for $x=0$...